# What is the correct way to abort an operation from the sudo password prompt?

Tags: sudo

Sometimes it amazes me the "little" things I *don't* know about Unix. For years now I have occasionally noted that I don't actually know how to deal with the sudo password prompt cleanly. Every once in a while I sudo something only to realize that I don't actually want to run the command at all. This happens rarely enough I always forget to ask but just often enough that I remember I still haven't learned the right way to abort.

Once sudo starts asking for a password it doesn't want to give up. You can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it. If you give it the right password it will run the command that I've decided I want to abort. The only solution I have found is to give it wrong passwords until it gives up asking and falls back to an su prompt which actually listens to a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This feels dirty to me. It's sad enough that I changed my mind about a command; not to be able to cancel it cleanly is just embarrassing.

What is the proper way to tell sudo to abort the attempt while at the password prompt?

Comment: `Ctrl-c` exits for me in bash and zsh...

Comment: @jasonwryan Now that's interesting. I wonder what is different about our configs. That would certainly seem like the obvious thing to do but it doesn't work on any of my systems.

Comment: Tested on Arch and Debian. Nothing I can see in `sudoers` that would account for it.

Comment: This is the closest thing I could find: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1455643

Comment: Confirmed, `Ctrl-C` is usable on Debian.

Comment: When I use `sudo` and a command by mistake, I usually hold on `CTRL-C` multiple times.

Comment: @ryekayo Do you do that because it does not respond to the first one or for some other reason?

Comment: I do it because it does not respond to the first one, maybe that is the wrong approach to doing it.. Not exactly sure

Comment: @ryekayo I'm confused about the "right" approach as well (hence asking this). It seems like it _should_ respond to the first `Ctrl+C` and for many people it is, but in some situations it obviously isn't. I have not figured out the difference yet.

Comment: Then maybe I am just impatient when I need to cancel a command.

Comment: What distribution and terminal emulator are you using? Do you see the same behavior on other distributions and terminals? Does `Ctrl+C` work if you run `xterm -e bash --norc`? What does `stty -a </dev/pts/42` return while at the sudo password prompt? Run `strace -p$(pidof sudo)` while at the password prompt and press `Ctrl+C`, what do you see?

Comment: @Caleb: maybe this only happens on the real terminal, as opposed to a X terminal emulator?

Comment: `Ctrl+C` works for me, but with a few seconds delay, I did not found any settings for this delay to make it shorter.

Comment: same as @T0maas, this delay is bonkers! See also https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=277348

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the task, then `kill %1` or even `kill -9 %1` to stop:

```
> sudo ls
[sudo] password for user:
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

```
[1]  +   512 Suspended                     sudo ls
> kill %1
[1]  + Suspended (tty output)        sudo ls
> kill -9 %1
[1]    Killed                        sudo ls
```

(In case you have more background tasks in your shell: The number you need to give after the percent sign is the one in brackets `[]`).

Comment: It depends on your system settings if it supports CTRL-C.

However, this is how you kill any task that won't respond to CTRL-C.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Just tested and neither ctrl+c nor ctrl+d would work at the password prompt