# Kitty shortcut to escape prompt

Tags: sudo, keyboard-shortcuts, prompt, read, kitty

Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/534851/272449) I have the following mapping in my kitty.conf to escape a stuck command quickly:

```
map ctrl+shift+z send_text normal \x1akill -9 %%\r
```

But for commands which prompt the user such as `read` or `sudo -k`,
the process stays alive suspended.
How can I stop the prompt from swallowing the kill command?

```bash
❯ jobs
❯ sudo -k echo hi
[sudo] password for janek: 

[1]  + 166575 suspended  sudo -k echo hi
❯ jobs
[1]  + suspended  sudo -k echo hi
❯ sleep 100
^Zsleep 0.1 && kill -9 %%

[2]  + 166667 suspended  sleep 100
❯ sleep 0.1 && kill -9 %%
[2]  + 166667 killed     sleep 100
```